# Child Target not inheriting pods from parent target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios-targets

I have two different targets in my project, with one being a copy of the other. I have now migrated my project to swift 3 and managed to get the main target building and running fine. The copy though seems to not find any of the pod files that I have imported. I checked the build settings for the target and realise that both the header search paths and library search paths are empty. I have the `$inherited` tag in there but it seems to show up as an empty string when you save it.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that it inherits the search paths from the main target in order for me to build and run it? It worked perfectly fine before I migrated the code.

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using?  Are you missing the new target in your Podfile?  If not, what happens when you do `pod update` ?

Comment: I am using version 1.1.1. It was missing from the Podfile, now it seems to be working. Thanks